# chrome extension, how to show a modal from context Menu option?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

On clicking the option on context menu (of my chrome extension) I want to show a modal on the page, which contains a form.
How do you implement this?
What I have found implemented right now:

- I can easily describe a form in contentScript.js and inject it.

Problems I have found:

- Defining the elements to be injected in javascript is tedious. (isn't there a better way)
- Website's CSS interferes with my injected elements

Possible solutions I have found:

- Shadow-DOM so that website's CSS does not interfere with the injected element.

Example:

- Pocket Chrome extension is exactly the type of action I want to build and it doesn't user shadow-DOM. How does it do?

Comment: You can add your UI inside an iframe declared in web_accessible_resources.